# How to create installer in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-express

I want to create installer for my project in visual studio 2015.

I try the following steps but does not find the
"Choose Other Projects -> Visual Studio Installer -> SetUp and Development" in my Visual Studio.

*Right Click on your Solution -> Add New Project -> Choose Other Projects -> Visual Studio Installer -> SetUp and Development -> Give the project Name*
[image]
[image]

I also try to install "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects"
But it gave the error like this

[image]

Comment: Could it be that the setup project template is missing because you're running Visual Studio Express, as opposed to the full Visual Studio? You might want to have a look at [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) or [Package a desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) for more options.

Comment: The Express edition does not allow installing extensions.  There is no point to it anymore, use the Community edition instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) for your needs.

After successful installation you go to  *Other Project Types > Visual Studio Installer* as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1e31.png).

Comment: I tried this, but the installation is disrupted midway with the following error message being displayed,

"Microsoft Visual Studio is required, but it is not installed on this computer. Please install it and retry."

I already have visual studio 2015 installed on my PC

Comment: @Yogesh Dhuke - as mentioned in other comments moving to a newer version is recommended